# Best way to convert csv data to dict

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file with following data

```
val1,val2,val3
1,2,3
22,23,33
```

So how can I convert data into dict

```
dict1 = { 'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}
dict2 = { 'val1': 22, 'val2': 23, 'val3': 33}
fp = open('file.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(fp)
for row in reader:
    ????
```

Thanks

Answer (score 38):

```
import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(open('myfile.csv'))
for row in reader:
    # profit !
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [csv.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader but maps the information read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional *fieldnames* parameter. The *fieldnames* parameter is a [`sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) whose elements are associated with the fields of the input data in order. These elements become the keys of the resulting dictionary. If the *fieldnames* parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the *csvfile* will be used as the *fieldnames*. If the row read has more fields than the fieldnames sequence, the remaining data is added as a sequence keyed by the value of *restkey*. If the row read has fewer fields than the fieldnames sequence, the remaining keys take the value of the optional *restval* parameter. Any other optional or keyword arguments are passed to the underlying [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instance...

Answer (score 5):

The cool thing with using 'csv' as mentioned in other answers here is that it can be used for reading a file (the obvious use case) but also parse a regular csv formatted string.

Example for reading a csv file:

```
import csv
with open('my_file.csv') as f:
   for line in csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=('val1', 'val2', 'val3')):
      print(line)
```

notice that you can explicitly pass the headers which you want be the keys, making it very easy to use csv files without headers.

Another use case is reading just a regular string with 'csv'

Example:

```
import csv
my_csv_string = 'val1, val2, val3'
my_csv_dict = next(csv.DictReader(StringIO(s), fieldnames=('key1', 'key2', 'key3')))
```

Anyway, `csv.DictReader()` is what you need..

Answer (score 4):

Oftentimes I feel like upgrading to pandas while manipulating CSVs. It gives you a whole new world of possibilities.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    d=row.to_dict()
    print(d)

print("")

print( df[df.val3>10].iloc[0].to_dict() )
print( list(df[['val3']]['val3']) )
```

Output:

```
{'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}
{'val1': 22, 'val2': 23, 'val3': 33}

{'val1': 22, 'val2': 23, 'val3': 33}
[3, 33]
```

Comment: I like pandas as well when handling CSVs. It gives you the whole CSV as one dict, and not as an iterable.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code  to convert you csv to dictionary as requested in your question

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as file:
    for i in csv.DictReader(file):
        print (dict(i))
```