# Creating a dictionary with values as another list

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have some data as below:

```
United Kingdom,57533000,London,6756000,Europe,1066,1945,-,English
United States,252177000,Washington DC,606900,North America,1776,1945,-,English
Venezuela,19733000,Caracas,1290087,Latin America,1811,1945,-,Spanish
Vietnam,67589000,Hanoi,1088862,Orient,1945,1977,-,Vietnamese
Yemen,1184300,San'a,427150,Asia,1918,1957,Islam,Arabic
Argentina,36955182,Buenos Aires,2033445,Latin America,1853,1945,-,Spanish
Brazil,172860370,Brasilia,286037,0Latin America,1822,1945,-,Portuguese
Bahrain,634137,Manama,34137,Persian Gulf,1973,1977,Islamic,Arabic
Cameroon,15421937,Yaounde,421937,Africa,1960,1974,-,Franch
Djibouti,451442,Djibouti,1442,Africa,1977,1980,-,Franch
Equatorial Guinea,474214,Malabo,74214,Africa,1991,1995,-,Franch
Fiji,832494,Suva,32494,Oceania,1970,1975,-,English
France,59329691,Paris,329691,Europe,486,1945,-,Franch
Greece,10601527,Athens,601527,Europe,1829,1945,-,Greek
Germany,82797408,Berlin,1797408,Europe,1871,1960,-,German
Honduras,6249598,Tegucigalpa,1249598,Latin America,1821,1945,-,Spanish
China,1261832482,Beijing,61832482,Asia,-221,1945,-,Chinese
Canada,31281092,Ottawa,1281092,North America,1867,1945,-,English
Hungary,10138844,Budapest,1138844,Europe,1001,1945,-,Hungerian
India,1014003817,New Delhi,14003817,Asia,1947,1950,-,Indian
Italy,57634327,Rome,3634327,Europe,1861,1950,-,Italian
Ireland,3797257,Dublin,797257,Europe,1921,1945,-,English
Japan,126549976,Tokio,16549976,Asia,-660,1955,-,Japanese
```

My requirement is to store the data in a dictionary as below:

```
{'Portuguese': ['Brazil'], 'Franch': ['Cameroon', 'Djibouti', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'France'], 'Chinese': ['China'], 'Vietnamese': ['Vietnam'], 'German': ['Germany'], 'English': ['United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Fiji', 'Canada', 'Ireland'], 'Japanese': ['Japan'], 'Greek': ['Greece'], 'Indian': ['India'], 'Spanish': ['Venezuela', 'Argentina', 'Honduras'], 'Arabic': ['Yemen', 'Bahrain'], 'Hungerian': ['Hungary'], 'Italian': ['Italy']}
```

Can someone help me achieve this?

The other queries posted as duplicate did not help me. I have added the code I tried. Please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert csv data to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387697/best-way-to-convert-csv-data-to-dict)

Comment: Here is my code I tried

Comment: countryData=open('filename.txt','r')
dictCountry={}
langList=[]
countryList=[]

def createList(langL,input):
    input=input.rstrip()
    country=input.split(',')[0]
    if input.split(',')[-1] in langL:
        countryList.append(country)
        return countryList

for line1 in countryData:
    line1=line1.rstrip()    
    lang1=line1.split(',')[-1]    
    if lang1 not in langList:
        langList.append(lang1)

for line2 in countryData:
    line2=line2.rstrip()
    lang=line2.split(',')[-1]
    dictCountry[lang]=createList(lang, line2)
print(dictCountry)

Comment: @EdChum -  My question was not "Can someone supply code for this requirement?"  . It was "How to achieve it?".  Any idea on how to create a list of values from the list and pair it with dict[language]?

Comment: @PhaniKumar please add your properly formatted code the question rather than as a comment, this will help people understand what you have tried :)

Comment: Some of the countries name are missing in the list which you have provided as expected output
For ex : English for Dublin,Europe.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of comments on your question asking you to post the code properly formatted on the question itself. This would have, for sure, gotten you a response earlier.

I took the code you pasted as a comment and attempted to format it, and I came up with this:

```
countryData=open('filename.txt','r') 
dictCountry={} 
langList=[] 
countryList=[] 

def createList(langL,input): 
    input=input.rstrip()
    country=input.split(',')[0] 
    if input.split(',')[-1] in langL: 
        countryList.append(country) 
    return countryList 

for line1 in countryData: 
    line1=line1.rstrip() 
    lang1=line1.split(',')[-1] 
    if lang1 not in langList: 
        langList.append(lang1) 

for line2 in countryData: 
    line2=line2.rstrip() 
    lang=line2.split(',')[-1] 
    dictCountry[lang]=createList(lang, line2) 

print(dictCountry)
```

There are a few issues with your attempt:

- Iterating multiple times on the same opened file. This will make the second `for` loop never run
- `countryList` is defined globally, so it could never hold just the current language's countries
- Once the content of `langList` is populated, it's never used

I changed it a little to a working solution:

```
f = open('filename.txt','r')
countryData = f.readlines()
f.close()

dictCountry = {}

for line in countryData:
    line = line.rstrip()
    lang = line.split(',')[-1]
    country = line.split(',')[0]
    if lang not in dictCountry:
        dictCountry[lang] = []

    dictCountry[lang].append(country)

print(dictCountry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the solution given below would help out.I am also attaching output what I am getting :

```
        f = open('lang.txt','r')
        countryData = f.readlines() //reading all contents of file
        f.close()

        dictCountry = {}

        for line in countryData:
            pos = 0

            line = line.rstrip()
            lang = line.split(',')[-1] //getting the lang name from eachline
            #updating the list of languages
            if lang not in dictCountry:
                dictCountry[lang] = []

            country = line.split(',') //splitting the line fro country names
            sub = ' '
            for i in country:
                if i in dictCountry.keys(): //ignoring lang name present in 
                    pass
                elif i.isalpha():
                    dictCountry[lang].append(i)
                elif i.find(sub)!= -1:
                    dictCountry[lang].append(i)
                else:
                    pass

        for i in dictCountry.keys():
            print i," : ",dictCountry[i]


**Output :
Portuguese  :  ['Brazil', 'Brasilia', '0Latin America']
Franch  :  ['Cameroon', 'Yaounde', 'Africa', 'Djibouti', 'Djibouti', 'Africa', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Malabo', 'Africa', 'France', 'Paris', 'Europe']
Chinese  :  ['China', 'Beijing', 'Asia']
Vietnamese  :  ['Vietnam', 'Hanoi', 'Orient']
German  :  ['Germany', 'Berlin', 'Europe']
English  :  ['United Kingdom', 'London', 'Europe', 'United States', 'Washington DC', 'North America', 'Fiji', 'Suva', 'Oceania', 'Canada', 'Ottawa', 'North America', 'Ireland', 'Dublin', 'Europe']
Japanese  :  ['Japan', 'Tokio', 'Asia']
Greek  :  ['Greece', 'Athens', 'Europe']
Indian  :  ['India', 'New Delhi', 'Asia']
Spanish  :  ['Venezuela', 'Caracas', 'Latin America', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 'Latin America', 'Honduras', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Latin America']
Arabic  :  ['Yemen', 'Asia', 'Islam', 'Bahrain', 'Manama', 'Persian Gulf', 'Islamic']
Hungerian  :  ['Hungary', 'Budapest', 'Europe']
Italian  :  ['Italy', 'Rome', 'Europe']**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the answer I could reach to:

f=open('country.txt','r')
countryData1=f.readlines()
f.close()

sourceDict={}
destDict={}

for lines in countryData1:
    lines=lines.rstrip()
    lang=lines.split(',')[-1]
    if lang not in sourceDict.keys():
        sourceDict[lang]=lines.split(',')[0]+","
    else:
        sourceDict[lang]+=lines.split(',')[0]+","    

for item in sourceDict.keys():
    sourceDict[item]=str(sourceDict[item]).rstrip(',')
    destDict[item]=str(sourceDict[item]).split(',')


for item in destDict.keys():
    print(item+ "   "+ str(destDict[item]))
```