# Parsing CSV data into a dict

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to pass csv data into an empty dict. Column A of the dict has the book title, column B the book's author. So once passed in, I'm hoping my dict will look like this:

```
books = {'Booktitle1':'Author1','Booktitle2':'Author2','Booktitle 3':'Author3'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert csv data to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387697/best-way-to-convert-csv-data-to-dict)

Comment: `for book, author in csv.reader(csvfile): books[book] = author` ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```py
import csv

with open('books.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    books = dict(line for line in reader if line)
```

The file like this:

```
Booktitle1,Author1
Booktitle2,Author2
Booktitle3,Author3
```

Will give you:

```py
books = {'Booktitle1': 'Author1', 'Booktitle2': 'Author2', 'Booktitle3': 'Author3'}
```

*The `if line` takes care of empty lines*

*If your file has a header, you can [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674406/9067617)*